# Why does Xubuntu's 'hdparm' command not return a faster result for my SSD (Crucial m4)?

Tags: ubuntu, performance, ssd, xubuntu

Here is my output:

`sda` is an *m4 Crucial* SSD
`sdb` is a 7200rpm hard disk

Should I not be expecting fast performance from the SSD? 
Is is using `TRIM` and `noatime`. Both  drives are formatted as `ext4`.

```
[Tue Jun 26 00:40:39 root@greg ] $ hdparm -Tt /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   8192 MB in  2.00 seconds = 4096.77 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 794 MB in  3.00 seconds = 264.64 MB/sec

[Tue Jun 26 00:40:57 root@greg ] $ hdparm -Tt /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 Timing cached reads:   8044 MB in  2.00 seconds = 4023.43 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 326 MB in  3.00 seconds = 108.58 MB/sec
[Tue Jun 26 00:41:12 root@greg ] $
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to answer your question without knowing more about the hardware of the computer where `hdparm` was run.

But my first "guess" would be that your computer only supports SATA II. The max (theoretical) throughput for SATA II is 300 MB/sec (~= 286 MiB/sec). Your result from `hdparm` of 264.64 MB/sec would appear to be good match to the "limitations" of SATA II .

---

One possible way to check my "guess" above would be to use the commands below.

```
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep speed
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb | grep speed
```

- **Note:** I think I have specified the correct `grep` string in the commands above. However, if it does not work, try leaving off the `grep` and see what you get.)

The output I expect you will get (from the `grep`) should look like the line below.

```
*   Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
```

The above indicates the controller the drive is attached to is SATA II since
3.0 Gbits/sec is 300 MBytes/sec (3000/10 bits per byte) ~= 286 MiB/sec.
(See also [**this section**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#SATA_revision_2.0_.28SATA_3_Gbit.2Fs.29) of the Wikipedia [SATA article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA).)

The results from running `sudo lshw -class storage` may also be of interest to you.